# How to display JSON data with HTML in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, vb.net

How do I display the JSON formatted in HTML in Angular? This is my current code in HTML:

```html
<h5>Konsep Produk</h5>
<br />
{{productConcept}}
```

This is a sample of the JSON data:

```
"key": "AAA",
"value": "<b>Heading</b>Description Here",
```

Comment: Use the JSON pipe : `{{productConcept | json}}`. Really, a simple Google search would have given you the answer, no need to ask for help here :)

Comment: Some like `<div [innerHTML]="productConcept.value"></div>`. make the trick. but it's possible was neccesary ["sanitize"](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer). For this, you can inject domSanitizer in constructor `constructor(public domSanitizer:DomSanitizer){}` and use `<div [innerHTML]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(productConcept.value)"></div>`